# Idea for improving answers

Tags: feature-request, answers

I am more or less a beginner with Python/Qt and some of my questions are already answered. Thanks to the community.

But unfortunately, most of the answers are written in C and not in Python. So my idea is to reopen these questions and ask for answers in Python. I'm sure I'm not the only who learns python because C is not the favour.

Comment: Making posts longer and harder to traverse is not an improvement.

Comment: *"I'm sure I'm not the only who learns python because C is not the favour."* What? What's wrong with C?

Comment: @Cody Gray There is nothing wrong with C, but I am on python and many questions are answerd in C. If a have a question I didn't catch the documentation, therefore I'm asking. Further, sometimes there will be just answer like 'duplicate question' (which link to a C - solution) if you ask for a python solution. I don't have an example on hand, but that happened to me sometimes.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Starting at the solution, I think if the code block feature shown in answers could be enhanced to display tabs, then the idea proposed by Papageno could be achieved. This would have some advantages:

- Solutions in more than one language can be associated with the original question.
- It avoids re-asking or re-openning the question and risking it being closed due to it being a "duplicate".
- It doesn't necessarily make the question too broad. For example, if the question is "In Spark how do i do XYZ using Scala?". It allows people to post multiple answers to that solution using for example Scala, Java, Python, R and so on. The question is the same but multiple solutions. Sure the default language tab shown in answers should be Scala (because that is what OP needed), but that answer can be translated into say python and encapsulated into the same answer as another tab.
- If code block tabs is implemented as an optional capability, then it does not change how SO works now. For example if the question is "in R how do I do ABC?", then only an R answer would be given. But it does allow someone else to say, for example "and this is how it can be done in S" (I made up S - because S follows R :-)

**One way** that this might be implemented, is as follows:

- Enhance the code block to support tabs.
- Modify the answer editor and leverage the "four backticks + language" notation to create a tab in the code block display.

  - A single code block surrounded by prose (i.e. non code) on either side results in no tabs being displayed. i.e. prose followed by code followed by prose displays exactly as it does now.
  - Multiple code blocks surrounded by prose form a tabbed code block. For example

    - prose
    - ''''Java
    - ''''python
    - prose
  - would result in a code block consisting of two tabs (i.e. Java and Python).
  - four back ticks with no language identifier would result in a default label of perhaps "text" or similar.
  - If code is not relevant, then the code block can simply be omitted, so no change to SO for this point.
  - If there is "prose" that is only relevant to a particular language, then this can easily be implemented as comments within that code block. For example, if there is a special python or scala or java or  "trick" being exploited, then it is appropriate to explain that "trick" within the code. Thus code specific "prose" and "generic answer" prose can still be accommodated. Besides, IMHO, code that is more than a few lines should include comments explaining what is going on anyways - IMHO.

(Apologies for my use of a list to illustrate the use of successive code blocks, but I wasn't sure how else to enter it here).

As I mentioned that is just one way that Papageno's idea could be implemented, I can imagine lots more ways and am not tied to that one.

Here is an image from the spark web site that illustrates how at least one other site has implemented this...

[image: Examples in Multiple Languages from Apache Spark Web Site]

Comment: NB: I had to use single quotes in my little example as when i tried using back ticks, they were interpreted as being an introduction for a code block. I didn't expect that to occur if the back ticks were embedded in a list. Anyway, I struggled with it for a while and settled on single quotes in place of back ticks.  *I am not proposing that backticks be replaced by single quotes for code block declarations.*

Answer (score 21):

No, don't mix up languages like that. That'd make the question too broad.

If there is a good question that should be answered in a different language, you could re-post it in said language.

Just make sure check if the new question isn't a duplicate, and to translate any code samples in the question to the other language, so the new question contains an MCVE.

Comment: "so the new question contains an MCVE" ... If the question is a debugging question, otherwise an MCVE is not required.

Comment: @TinyGiant Not sure what is your suggestion - you seem to be against "translate any code samples in the question to the other language" ... but not doing so pretty much guarantees "too broad" closure for complete "translate this code for me" posts...

Comment: I would't say 'too broad', I would say 'more functional'. If there are same questions for different languages and answers in different threads, that will make SO 'too broad'

Comment: A site enhancement could be to have a "code section" for the answer. Different users could be encouraged to provide the same solution in a different language. The default language solution to be shown would be the programming language the question was asked (if specified). Solutions in other languages could be viewed by selecting a tab on the solutions code block(s). So for papagano's scenario, a solution might be asked in relation to C which would be the default. Others can then elect to provide evuvalents in Python or Java or whatever else is usdful.

Comment: @GMc: A more flexible solution would be for code snippets to have language tabs. A good answer does explain the code, though, so having the code in a different language is likely problematic.

Comment: @cerbrus agreed about language tabs, but my thought re explaining code specifics would be comments and thus appear in the relevant code blocks/tabs. Explaining the solution would (should?) be in more generic terms (i.e. not code specific) and thus be in the main body of the answer. Of course there are lots of possible variations, but this would be similar to what is currently available on SO (i.e comments in code blocks and prose in the main body of answers).

Comment: @GMc: _A site enhancement could be to have a "code section" for the answer_
This would be a fine solution, so it would be possible to generate a 'code solution' database.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov sure, if it has code and requires it then it should be translated, but if it's not a debugging question then it isn't required and there doesn't have to be any code at all.

Comment: Exactly, just like SO is now. The enhancement is to intoduce some construct in the editor that makes 4 back ticks followed by a language identifier a tab code block. If there is another 4 back ticks and language identifier following that one with no intervening prose then it becomes the next tab in that code block. Intervening prose results in a new code block. Of course i am completely open to a more robust / clearer way of implementing it, that is just an idea as to how to do it.